# WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync and File.Exists

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, webclient

I'm using the following code to download a file and verify if the download succeeded:

```
        try
        {
            UpdateAvailable = false;
            Downloading = true;

            using (var webclient = new WebClient { CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore) })
            {
                var file = Path.Combine(basePath, filename);
                await webclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(updaterexe_fileurl, Path.Combine(basePath, updaterexe_filename));
                await webclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(updatefileurl, file);
            }

            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Error = "Error downloading update. Please try again.";
                Log.Error("Error downloading update. Please try again (file does not exist).");
            }
            else
            {
                DownloadReady = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error downloading update: " + ex);
            Error = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            Downloading = false;
        }
```

This works in most cases. But I got multiple reports from end-users that sometimes they get the 'try again' error message.

How is this even possible? Clearly, WebClient didn't throw an exception, but it also failed to download the file (it did not exist on disk).

Is this a caching issue? Am I missing any other error handling?

If it's a disk caching issue, I thought about adding the following:

```
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 3 || !File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                count++;
            }
```

But this feels very hacky.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am awaiting it right? The download is around ~8Mb. so if it's not awaited I should be getting way more error reports.

Comment: @AkashKava What does `await` do?

Comment: What's the point of downloading to `file` and then checking if `filename` exists?

Comment: @ta.speot.is oh good catch! I think the end-users who run into this run the program starting in a different startup location. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You download to `file`, which is `Path.Combine(basePath, filename)` but you never check to see whether `file` exists, you check to see whether `filename` exists.

If `basePath` and the current working directory differ, the file "won't exist".

Comment: Yes! Good catch, thanks. Accepted (when I am able to :p)

Comment: yeah this was definitely the issue. And while i'm at it, I also added a check for the other file :) Thanks a lot.